# How do you use /execute if to detect a renamed item in a players inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to figure out how to detect renamed items in someone's inventory. I've been able to use /execute if to detect an item, but I can't figure out how to detect a renamed item. This is what I tried: `execute if entity @a[name=(username),nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:music_disc_far",tag:{display:{Name:"another username"}}}]}]`

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is correct, but it's the `Name` tag that is causing the problems.

As of 1.13, the `Name` tag is now a JSON text component. This means, instead of storing the item's custom name directly in the string tag, it is stored in the JSON text component, which is then inserted into the string.

A simple JSON text component of your use looks like this:

```
{"text":"another username"}
```

Luckily, anvils don't let you make special formatting, because otherwise the text component would look *way* more complicated.

All you need to do is insert the code snippet above into the `Name` tag!
But be careful because there is one more twist: The first `"` in the text component is treated by Minecraft as the end of the `Name` string tag! To tell Minecraft to treat the `"` as part of the string and not the closing delimiter, simply put a backslash `\` before it. Your final `Name` tag should look like this:

```
Name:"{\"text\":\"another username\"}"
```

Now this can look quite complicated, but 1.15 saves you the pain of escaping all those `"`s with a simple extra tool. If you are in 1.15 it is recommended to do the following instead!

Instead of having to escape every single double quote `"`, place the entire `Name` tag string in single quotes `'` instead! This means you can use double quotes inside your string as much as you like! Note that this does mean that you now have to escape every *single quote* with a backslash `\`, but chances are your custom name shouldn't contain too many of those.
Here is the updated `Name` tag taking these changes into account:

```
Name:'{"text":"another username"}'
```

Please note that differently formatted texts are not treated by the system as a match, even if the text itself is the same!

Explore more JSON text by learning [`/tellraw`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tellraw), and learn about JSON text using the Minecraft Wiki page [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Raw_JSON_text_format).